# Any way to free up the Microsoft Wireless mouse wheel?

Tags: mouse

The Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 5000 is easy to disassemble, but nothing I do will unstick the wheel. The rubber wheel spins on a drum-like encoder machanism, and it is not turning freely. This is the fate of all my microsoft wheel mice after about a year of use. I can spray a silcone lube on the drum but this only works for few minutes, then the wheel starts to stick again. I've cleaned all the visible dirt out, and doused it with a lot of isopropyl to no avail. Suggestions? I am interested in salvaging this device, not buying a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The gummy rubber finger ring has only a few thousandths clearance, so any imperfection or wear on the wheel causes it to rub on the wheel enclosure. Wear is caused by use, and probably aided by disintegration from atmospheric ozone. I replaced the gummy ring with a small rubber band, wheel is very free now. Will have to find a machinist to make a more permanent ring.

Comment: +1 disgusting. Don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about sanding the inside of the wheel enclosure to make it a few thousands larger?